# LIbreOffice Muffin is barely readable

Tags: libreoffice, accessibility

I've been trying the LibreOffice ribbon equivalent, but I find the menu items almost impossible to read. As the screenshot shows, it gives dark grey text on a darker grey background.

Is there a theme that would give better contrast?

[image]

Comment: You can see [this](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/20997/how-to-change-themes/)

Comment: That allows me to change the icon theme, but the text-background contrast on the ribbon tabs is unaffected. Changing the system theme makes no difference either.

Comment: So LibreOffice toolbar color scheme is binded to System colors. I think you will solve it if you change it. Are you using Kubuntu?

Comment: No, Unity. When I change the system theme, the title bar changes but the tabs stay the same colour.

Comment: Look at desktop appearance. You will see at bottom right side of change background settings.

Comment: Couldn't find the button you mention, but the High Contrast theme seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Not? Really, it's not a button, but a combobox. So even Radiance or Ambience are dark themes at your desktop? Unfortunately Unity interface is not so customizable as other GUI managers. In this case, Canonical make good thing to discontinue it.